# Heatmaps of Zipcodes using R

Tags: r, geospatial, interactive

Please I am trying to plot different zipcodes in R on the map for houston, TX .I already plotted the zipcodes  which appear as colored circles on the map .How do I plot the actual zipcodes on the map so that when you hover the mouse on the map the zipcodes appear or displays.?

```
library(ggplot2)
library(maps)
library(ggmap)

x1 <- as.character(data$zips)
lonlat_sample <- sapply(x1 , function(x1){as.numeric(geocode(x1))})

lonlat1 <- t(lonlat_sample)
complete1 <- data.frame(data,lonlat1)

colnames(complete1) <- c("zips", "ER","long","lat")

map <- get_map(location = "harris county", zoom=9) 
mapPoints <- ggmap(map, fullpage=TRUE) +
  geom_point(aes(x = long, y = lat, size = ER, col="class"), data = complete1, alpha = .8)
mapPoints
```

Comment: Can you share the code that got you to the current question?

Comment: @chh, please edit your question and add the code to it.

Comment: @chh, Thanks for editing your code. One more thing, if possible, would you please post example data. The post on [reproducible examples](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) talks about how to do this.

Comment: If you want interactivity, "o that when you hover the mouse on the map the zipcodes appear or displays", you'll need something like `ggvis`, or a Shiny app. `ggplot` produces static graphs.

Comment: @Gregor , Okay trying that to see how i will be able to use that

Comment: @Gregor , so in the case of the ggvis what will the be the environment ( ie env = parent.frame())  ,will this be?   `ggvis(data=null, ......, env = parent.frame())`

Comment: @chh, I don't know how to solve your problem. However, I though I could help you write a question that other people would be able easily answer.